# Install spynner in python on Windows 7

Tags: python, spynner

I want to install spynner in python 2.7.9, on windows 7. I have tried using 'pip' but it is giving error. Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "c:\users\paramvir\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Paramvir\autopy\setup.py", line 222, in <
module>
        EXT_MODULES = create_ext_modules('src/')
      File "c:\users\paramvir\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Paramvir\autopy\setup.py", line 180, in c
reate_ext_modules
        raise IOError('windows directory not found at: "%s"' % win_dir)
    IOError: windows directory not found at: "c:\users\paramvir\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Paramvi
r\autopy\windows\win32"
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "c:\users\paramvir\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Paramvir\autopy\setup.py", line 222, in <modu
le>

    EXT_MODULES = create_ext_modules('src/')

  File "c:\users\paramvir\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Paramvir\autopy\setup.py", line 180, in creat
e_ext_modules

    raise IOError('windows directory not found at: "%s"' % win_dir)

IOError: windows directory not found at: "c:\users\paramvir\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Paramvir\au
topy\windows\win32"
```

how do I install spynner? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i recently got the same error as you are , and i fix it without using the pip command

1. download the spynner zip file and unzip to the C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages 
   here is the link:
   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner
2. download the autopy file and install the windows installer
   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/0.51